# return statement showing abnormality while using elif instead of else in function definition

Tags: python-3.x

I used `elif` instead of `else` in my function definition *(day_in_month)* and it showed an error while executing the function :

**UnboundLocalError: local variable 'month_days' referenced before assignment**

But after using `else` instead of `elif` , it didn't showed any error.

Code giving error is below !!!

```
def is_leap(year):
    if year % 4 == 0:
        if year % 100 == 0:
            if year % 400 == 0:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return True
    else:
        return False

def days_in_month(year,month):
    if is_leap == True:
        month_days = [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    elif is_leap == False:
        month_days = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    return month_days[month-1]

year = int(input("Enter a year: "))
month = int(input("Enter a month: "))

days = days_in_month(year, month)
print(days)
```

Now I have fixed my code , but what is the reason behind this anomaly ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def foo1(year: int) -> bool:
    "find a year is leapyear or not"
    if year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0:
        return True
    return year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 == 0

def foo2(year: int, month: int):
    "find max days in a month"
    if foo1(year) and month == 2:
        return 29
    return [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31][month - 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

it's because you didn't call function `is_leap` properly..

```
if is_leap == True:
```

function `is_leap` is parameterized it takes one argument `year`, but while calling you didn't pass it
at both position `if` and `elif`, it must be like this,

```
if is_leap(year) == True:
```

this error occured because no any block executed neither `if` nor `elif`,
so your `month_days` list doesn't created ,

to avoid errors like this, code something like below i did,

```
def is_leap(year):
    if year % 4 == 0:
        if year % 100 == 0:
            if year % 400 == 0:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return True
    else:
        return False

def days_in_month(year,month):
    month_days = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    if is_leap(year) == True:
        month_days[1] = 29
        
    return month_days[month-1]

year = int(input("Enter a year: "))
month = int(input("Enter a month: "))

days = days_in_month(year, month)
print(days)
```